# Why does my iPhone application crash right after 1 hour?

Tags: iphone

My iPhone application is crashing right after 1 hour is passed (I am using development prov. profile). Is there any limitation of development prov profile? Is it related to memory leaks? But why exactly 1 hour?

Comment: We would need to see what you are doing to be able to help you.

Comment: Can I note that I'm impressed someone used an iPhone app for an hour? :)

Comment: Cheer up - when the iPhone 3GS comes out tomorrow, maybe it'll only take 40 minutes to crash.

Answer (score 2):

- Connect the iphone to Organizer "XCode--> Window menu --> Organizer".
- Check the crash logs.

-Edit
Missed that part that you are developing the App., run the App in debug mode and check the debugger console, type in - **bt**  to back trace the stack.